# unable to find an inherited method for function ‘vif’ for signature ‘"integer"’

Tags: r, regression

I am unable to run the vif command

```
mData = read.csv(file.choose())
attach(mData)
head(mData)
reg1= lm(MPG~Weight)
plot(reg1)
summary(reg1)
vif(Weight)
```

It throws an error like:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘vif’ for signature ‘"integer"’

Comment: what is `vif` and where do you get it? if this has to do with variance inflation, you need to give it more than a single variable. and a reproducible example would help since we dont have access to your files

Answer (score 6):

The command `vif` exists at both package `car` and package `usdm`, and the command objects in these packages are also different. R can't identify which `vif` you are trying to use.

To solve the problem, try below command:

```
detach("package:usdm", unload=TRUE)
library(car)
```

Then run

```
vif(your_model)
```